# How to get 2010 city demographic data by census block group

Tags: data, united-states, census, demography

I am doing machine learning research on US cities (New York City, Los Angeles, San Francisco, Chicago, Seattle). I try to predict some demographic data based on features in each **census block group**.

I am looking for **2010 household median income data by census block group** in five cities above. I hope the data can contain the census block group location (lat/long or coordinates) and its median household income. I have looked through some database websites such as FactFinder, NYCOpenData, US Census Bureau, and I also looked through similar questions....but I haven't found what I want.

Any idea where I can get the desired data? Or is it possible to get such desired data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest [NHGIS Data finder](https://data2.nhgis.org/main). They have ACS 2010-2014 data available and you can download the GIS boundary files as well. Note that you have to register (for free).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is the [TIGER/Line® with Selected Demographic and Economic Data](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-data.html) which states "These geodatabases were created using ArcGIS 10.1."

[image]

<strike>I was able to pull income from [FactFinder (directed there by US Census)](http://factfinder.census.gov/bkmk/table/1.0/en/ACS/14_5YR/DP03/) and I produced this "Economic" income result for Chicago through the advanced search:
[image]</strike>

The data can be downloaded after you produce your report.

Comment: Hi Kittii, thanks for your reply. I also found this, but this is a summary for the whole Chicago city, but I want detailed data for each census block group in Chicago....

Comment: @gladys0313 did you try the TIGER files with ArcGIS?

Comment: I am not sure whether I get your meaning, could you explain in more details or share a link?

Comment: @gladys0313 There is the TIGER/Line® with Selected Demographic and Economic Data which states "These geodatabases were created using ArcGIS 10.1."   https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-data.html

Comment: @gladys0313 I included a screenshot in my answer

Comment: thanks for your comment, I am looking at this. The data file is in format gdbtable and so on, which I haven't used before, so I am learning how to read it.

Answer (score 1):

The Maptitude Mapping software from Caliper Corporation will allow you to select all of the Census Block Groups for an area and see the geographic information as well as the Median Income value for each block group.

You would have to purchase the software and the additional block group data.

The tools in Maptitude make it easy to visually select the block groups or select using a query.  The results can be exported to Excel or other tabular formats.